# how does map side join split the input files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If I had two input folders each contains 100 input files, and I used map-side join. I wanna know how  many mapper tasks the hadoop will create. How does hadoop to split the input files when we were using map-side join.

Comment: Hadoop creates number of mappers=number of input splits. It doesnt depend if u are using a Map side join or a reduce side join. If u want to controll the number of mappers then create a custom inputformat and a custom recordreader

Comment: no, map side join is special, I'm looking into the class compositeinputformat. how many mappers depends on how many input files rather than splits. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map side joins of exactly 100 files in each of the sides will spawn 100 map tasks.